# Why does Postgres choose to perform seq scan on a large table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have this query which joins a few tables followed by groupbys on lots of fields.

```
SELECT a.SVC_ORD_NBR
        ,a.PO_NBR
        ,f.CUST_NBR as SHIPTO_NBR
        ,f.CUST_NAME
        ,f.CUST_ID
        ,f.CUST_LVL_2_NBR as Fleet_num
        ,f.CUST_LVL_2_NAME as Fleet
        ,f.CITY_NAME as SHIPTO_CITY
        ,f.STATE_CD as SHIPTO_STATE
        ,a.CREATE_DTM
        ,e.START_DTM as ACTVTY_START
        ,e.END_DTM as ACTVTY_END
        ,e.OPER_NBR
        ,o.DEBIT_MEMO_DTM
        ,o.CLOSE_DTM
        ,c.EQUIP_NBR as SAP_EQUIP_NBR
        ,c.TECH_NBR as Door_ID
        ,c.EQUIP_TYP_CD
        ,c.EQUIP_TYP_DESC
        ,c.BEGIN_WRNTY_DTE
        ,c.END_WRNTY_DTE
        ,b.REPLCMT_DTE
        ,h.PRIORITY_CD
        ,h.PRIORITY_DESC
        ,b.REPLCMT_CYCLE_CNT
        ,b.PREV_REPLCMT_DTE
        ,b.PREV_REPLCMT_CYCLE_CNT
        ,d.PROD_CD
        ,d.PRIM_PROD_DESC
        ,d.CUST_PROD_CTGY_CD
        ,b.ACTVTY_TYP_CD
        ,b.ACTVTY_TYP_DESC
        ,b.QTY
        ,b.UOM
        ,b.GRS_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,b.DISC_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,b.NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.STD_LABR_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.OVTM_LABR_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.TRAVEL_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.MATL_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.TAX_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.FRT_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,h.PM_ACTVTY_TYP_CD
        ,h.PM_ACTVTY_TYP_DESC
        ,b.CAUSE_CD
        ,b.CAUSE_DESC
        ,a.BRNCH_ID
        ,br.BRNCH_CD
        ,br.BRNCH_NAME
        ,SAP_SLS_ORG_NAME   
  FROM DMT_MAS_SVC_ORD_FACT a 
  INNER JOIN DMT_MAS_SVC_ACTVTY_FACT b on a.SVC_ORD_ID=b.SVC_ORD_ID
  INNER JOIN DMT_MAS_SVC_ACTVTY_DEGEN_DIM e on e.SVC_ACTVTY_ID=b.SVC_ACTVTY_ID
  INNER JOIN DMT_MAS_EQUIP_STORE_DIM c on b.EQUIP_STORE_ID=c.EQUIP_STORE_ID 
  INNER JOIN DMT_MAS_PROD_DIM d on b.PROD_ID=d.PROD_ID 
  INNER JOIN DMT_MAS_CUST_DIM f on a.SHIPTO_CUST_ID=f.CUST_ID
  INNER JOIN DMT_MAS_SVC_ORD_MISC_DIM h on a.SVC_ORD_MISC_DIM_ID = h.SVC_ORD_MISC_DIM_ID
  INNER JOIN DMT_MAS_SVC_ORD_DEGEN_DIM o on o.SVC_ORD_ID = a.SVC_ORD_ID
  INNER JOIN DMT_MAS_BRNCH_DIM br on br.BRNCH_ID = a.BRNCH_ID
WHERE CUST_LVL_2_NBR IN ('0080000268')
    AND e.START_DTM>='2016-01-01'
    AND f.SRC_SYS_DEL_FLAG != 'Y'
    AND CUST_NAME NOT LIKE '%USE%'
    AND CUST_NAME NOT LIKE '%DNU%'
    AND CUST_NAME NOT LIKE '%CLOSED%'
    AND CUST_NAME NOT LIKE '%use%'
    AND CUST_NAME NOT LIKE '%RELOCATED%'
    AND CUST_NAME NOT LIKE '%OLD%'
    AND CREATE_DTM >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1.5 years'
GROUP BY a.SVC_ORD_NBR
        ,a.PO_NBR
        ,f.CUST_NBR
        ,f.CUST_NAME
        ,f.CUST_ID
        ,f.CUST_LVL_2_NBR
        ,f.CUST_LVL_2_NAME
        ,f.CITY_NAME
        ,f.STATE_CD
        ,e.START_DTM
        ,e.END_DTM
        ,e.OPER_NBR
        ,c.EQUIP_NBR
        ,c.TECH_NBR
        ,c.EQUIP_TYP_CD
        ,c.EQUIP_TYP_DESC
        ,c.BEGIN_WRNTY_DTE
        ,c.END_WRNTY_DTE
        ,b.REPLCMT_DTE
        ,h.PRIORITY_CD
        ,h.PRIORITY_DESC
        ,b.REPLCMT_CYCLE_CNT
        ,b.PREV_REPLCMT_DTE
        ,b.PREV_REPLCMT_CYCLE_CNT
        ,d.PROD_CD
        ,d.PRIM_PROD_DESC
        ,d.CUST_PROD_CTGY_CD
        ,b.ACTVTY_TYP_CD
        ,b.ACTVTY_TYP_DESC
        ,b.QTY
        ,b.UOM
        ,b.GRS_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,b.DISC_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,b.NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.STD_LABR_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.OVTM_LABR_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.TRAVEL_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.MATL_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.TAX_NET_AMT_DCRNCY
        ,a.FRT_NET_AMT_DCRNCY   
        ,h.PM_ACTVTY_TYP_CD
        ,h.PM_ACTVTY_TYP_DESC
        ,b.CAUSE_CD
        ,b.CAUSE_DESC
        ,a.CREATE_DTM
        ,a.BRNCH_ID
        ,br.BRNCH_CD
        ,br.BRNCH_NAME
        ,SAP_SLS_ORG_NAME
        ,o.DEBIT_MEMO_DTM
        ,o.CLOSE_DTM
```

It takes about 20 minutes to complete the query which returns 33080 rows. I ran `explain analyze` on the query and it turned out majority of the time is taken on `seq scan`. Second time-consuming task is `hash join`.

[image]

To be exact, it is the table `DMT_MAS_SVC_ACTVTY_FACT`, which has 6m rows, the seq scan is performed on.

```
Seq Scan on dmt_mas_svc_actvty_fact b (cost=0.00..397,938.32 rows=6,851,932 width=730) (actual time=0.029..2,427.990 rows=6,851,932 loops=1)
```

As far as the `hash join`, it has to do with `svc_ord_id` field of table `dmt_mas_svc_actvty_fact` which is already indexed. So I guess there is nothing to do there.

```
Hash Join (cost=189,428.58..613,158.11 rows=9,647 width=2,916) (actual time=1,021.686..5,234.921 rows=36,276 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (b.svc_ord_id = a.svc_ord_id)
```

I don't understand while expensive `seq scan` is done for such a big table. What can I do to improve the performance? The full output of `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` is below

```
'Group  (cost=639562.36..639907.96 rows=3072 width=4770) (actual time=6190.734..6250.961 rows=33080 loops=1)'
'  Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, a.create_dtm, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, o.debit_memo_dtm, o.close_dtm, c.equip_nbr, c.tech_nbr, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, b.replcmt_dte, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, d.prod_cd, d.prim_prod_desc, d.cust_prod_ctgy_cd, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, a.brnch_id, br.brnch_cd, br.brnch_name, f.sap_sls_org_name'
'  Group Key: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, f.cust_id, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, c.equip_nbr, c.tech_nbr, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, b.replcmt_dte, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, d.prod_cd, d.prim_prod_desc, d.cust_prod_ctgy_cd, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, a.create_dtm, a.brnch_id, br.brnch_cd, br.brnch_name, o.debit_memo_dtm, o.close_dtm'
'  Buffers: shared hit=596201 read=461954'
'  ->  Sort  (cost=639562.36..639570.04 rows=3072 width=4770) (actual time=6190.729..6200.892 rows=33678 loops=1)'
'        Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, f.cust_id, a.create_dtm, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, o.debit_memo_dtm, o.close_dtm, c.equip_nbr, c.tech_nbr, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, b.replcmt_dte, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, d.prod_cd, d.prim_prod_desc, d.cust_prod_ctgy_cd, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, a.brnch_id, br.brnch_cd, br.brnch_name, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name'
'        Sort Key: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, f.cust_id, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, c.equip_nbr, c.tech_nbr, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, b.replcmt_dte, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, d.prod_cd, d.prim_prod_desc, d.cust_prod_ctgy_cd, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, a.create_dtm, a.brnch_id, br.brnch_cd, br.brnch_name, o.debit_memo_dtm, o.close_dtm'
'        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 18914kB'
'        Buffers: shared hit=596201 read=461954'
'        ->  Hash Join  (cost=189480.95..639384.42 rows=3072 width=4770) (actual time=1020.562..5907.187 rows=33678 loops=1)'
'              Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, f.cust_id, a.create_dtm, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, o.debit_memo_dtm, o.close_dtm, c.equip_nbr, c.tech_nbr, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, b.replcmt_dte, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, d.prod_cd, d.prim_prod_desc, d.cust_prod_ctgy_cd, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, a.brnch_id, br.brnch_cd, br.brnch_name, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name'
'              Hash Cond: (a.brnch_id = br.brnch_id)'
'              Buffers: shared hit=596201 read=461954'
'              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=189430.29..639291.52 rows=3072 width=4494) (actual time=1019.813..5880.117 rows=33678 loops=1)'
'                    Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.brnch_id, b.replcmt_dte, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, c.equip_nbr, c.tech_nbr, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, d.prod_cd, d.prim_prod_desc, d.cust_prod_ctgy_cd, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc, o.debit_memo_dtm, o.close_dtm'
'                    Join Filter: (a.svc_ord_id = o.svc_ord_id)'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=596177 read=461954'
'                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=189429.86..635368.92 rows=3072 width=4486) (actual time=1019.797..5748.503 rows=33678 loops=1)'
'                          Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.brnch_id, a.svc_ord_id, b.replcmt_dte, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, b.svc_ord_id, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, c.equip_nbr, c.tech_nbr, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, d.prod_cd, d.prim_prod_desc, d.cust_prod_ctgy_cd, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=461304 read=461954'
'                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=189429.44..631560.20 rows=3072 width=3798) (actual time=1019.787..5630.930 rows=33678 loops=1)'
'                                Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.brnch_id, a.svc_ord_id, b.replcmt_dte, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, b.svc_ord_id, b.prod_id, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, c.equip_nbr, c.tech_nbr, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=326590 read=461954'
'                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=189429.01..627565.55 rows=3072 width=3074) (actual time=1019.776..5484.314 rows=33678 loops=1)'
'                                      Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.brnch_id, a.svc_ord_id, b.replcmt_dte, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, b.svc_ord_id, b.equip_store_id, b.prod_id, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.oper_nbr, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=191763 read=461954'
'                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=189428.58..613158.11 rows=9647 width=2916) (actual time=1014.000..5326.408 rows=36276 loops=1)'
'                                            Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.brnch_id, a.svc_ord_id, b.replcmt_dte, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.qty, b.uom, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, b.svc_ord_id, b.svc_actvty_id, b.equip_store_id, b.prod_id, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc'
'                                            Hash Cond: (b.svc_ord_id = a.svc_ord_id)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=46718 read=461954'
'                                            ->  Seq Scan on public.dmt_mas_svc_actvty_fact b  (cost=0.00..397938.32 rows=6851932 width=730) (actual time=0.015..2443.898 rows=6851932 loops=1)'
'                                                  Output: b.svc_actvty_id, b.svc_actvty_ssk, b.svc_ord_id, b.actvty_typ_cd, b.actvty_typ_desc, b.cause_cd, b.cause_desc, b.post_dtm, b.ntfcn_id, b.tchn_id, b.truck_sloc_id, b.brnch_id, b.prod_id, b.equip_store_id, b.qty, b.uom, b.cost_amt, b.grs_amt_dcrncy, b.disc_amt_dcrncy, b.net_amt_dcrncy, b.unbill_net_amt_dcrncy, b.dcrncy_cd, b.grs_amt_bcrncy, b.disc_amt_bcrncy, b.net_amt_bcrncy, b.unbill_net_amt_bcrncy, b.bcrncy_cd, b.grs_amt_usd, b.disc_amt_usd, b.net_amt_usd, b.unbill_net_amt_usd, b.etl_job_invk, b.etl_job_name, b.etl_batch_id, b.etl_create_dtm, b.etl_lod_dtm, b.etl_msng_fk_flag, b.src_sys_cd, b.svc_ord_ssk, b.begin_wrnty_dte, b.replcmt_dte, b.prev_replcmt_dte, b.prev_part_dys, b.replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_replcmt_cycle_cnt, b.prev_part_cycles'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=320 read=329099'
'                                            ->  Hash  (cost=189409.49..189409.49 rows=1527 width=2186) (actual time=1011.803..1011.803 rows=11674 loops=1)'
'                                                  Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.brnch_id, a.svc_ord_id, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc'
'                                                  Buckets: 16384 (originally 2048)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 2447kB'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=46398 read=132855'
'                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=27443.65..189409.49 rows=1527 width=2186) (actual time=174.967..1001.413 rows=11674 loops=1)'
'                                                        Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.brnch_id, a.svc_ord_id, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc'
'                                                        Buffers: shared hit=46398 read=132855'
'                                                        ->  Hash Join  (cost=27443.36..187746.60 rows=1527 width=1638) (actual time=174.954..962.645 rows=12780 loops=1)'
'                                                              Output: a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.brnch_id, a.svc_ord_id, a.svc_ord_misc_dim_id, f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name'
'                                                              Hash Cond: (a.shipto_cust_id = f.cust_id)'
'                                                              Buffers: shared hit=9145 read=132855'
'                                                              ->  Seq Scan on public.dmt_mas_svc_ord_fact a  (cost=0.00..158932.11 rows=361564 width=436) (actual time=158.805..894.021 rows=236011 loops=1)'
'                                                                    Output: a.svc_ord_id, a.src_sys_cd, a.svc_ord_ssk, a.svc_ord_nbr, a.prim_ntfcn_id, a.asgn_tchn_id, a.brnch_id, a.shipto_cust_id, a.soldto_cust_id, a.payer_cust_id, a.svc_ord_misc_dim_id, a.equip_store_id, a.create_dte_id, a.create_dtm, a.bill_dte_id, a.bill_dtm, a.response_hrs, a.response_work_hrs, a.response_to_fix_hrs, a.response_to_fix_work_hrs, a.fix_to_bill_hrs, a.fix_to_bill_work_hrs, a.po_nbr, a.not_to_exceed, a.matl_cost, a.labr_cost, a.std_labr_hrs, a.ovtm_labr_hrs, a.matl_net_amt_dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_unbill_dcrncy, a.std_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_dcrncy, a.labr_net_amt_unbill_dcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_dcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_dcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_dcrncy, a.dcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_bcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_unbill_bcrncy, a.std_labr_net_amt_bcrncy, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_bcrncy, a.labr_net_amt_unbill_bcrncy, a.travel_net_amt_bcrncy, a.frt_net_amt_bcrncy, a.tax_net_amt_bcrncy, a.bcrncy, a.matl_net_amt_usd, a.matl_net_amt_unbill_usd, a.std_labr_net_amt_usd, a.ovtm_labr_net_amt_usd, a.labr_net_amt_unbill_usd, a.travel_net_amt_usd, a.frt_net_amt_usd, a.tax_net_amt_usd, a.ntfcn_text, a.etl_job_invk, a.etl_job_name, a.etl_batch_id, a.etl_create_dtm, a.etl_lod_dtm, a.etl_msng_fk_flag, a.response_hrs_wo_wkends'
'                                                                    Filter: (a.create_dtm >= (now() - '1 year 6 mons'::interval))'
'                                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 848681'
'                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=7095 read=132855'
'                                                              ->  Hash  (cost=27356.48..27356.48 rows=6950 width=1206) (actual time=5.960..5.960 rows=1893 loops=1)'
'                                                                    Output: f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name'
'                                                                    Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 251kB'
'                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=2050'
'                                                                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.dmt_mas_cust_dim f  (cost=155.87..27356.48 rows=6950 width=1206) (actual time=0.601..5.079 rows=1893 loops=1)'
'                                                                          Output: f.cust_nbr, f.cust_name, f.cust_id, f.cust_lvl_2_nbr, f.cust_lvl_2_name, f.city_name, f.state_cd, f.sap_sls_org_name'
'                                                                          Recheck Cond: ((f.cust_lvl_2_nbr)::text = '0080000268'::text)'
'                                                                          Filter: ((f.src_sys_del_flag <> 'Y'::bpchar) AND ((f.cust_name)::text !~~ '%USE%'::text) AND ((f.cust_name)::text !~~ '%DNU%'::text) AND ((f.cust_name)::text !~~ '%CLOSED%'::text) AND ((f.cust_name)::text !~~ '%use%'::text) AND ((f.cust_name)::text !~~ '%RELOCATED%'::text) AND ((f.cust_name)::text !~~ '%OLD%'::text))'
'                                                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 185'
'                                                                          Heap Blocks: exact=2039'
'                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=2050'
'                                                                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on lvl2_nbr_idx  (cost=0.00..154.13 rows=8227 width=0) (actual time=0.339..0.339 rows=2078 loops=1)'
'                                                                                Index Cond: ((f.cust_lvl_2_nbr)::text = '0080000268'::text)'
'                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=11'
'                                                        ->  Index Scan using svc_ord_misc_dim_pk on public.dmt_mas_svc_ord_misc_dim h  (cost=0.29..1.08 rows=1 width=556) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=12780)'
'                                                              Output: h.svc_ord_misc_dim_id, h.src_sys_cd, h.svc_loc_dtm_zone, h.create_by, h.bi_typ_cd, h.bi_typ_desc, h.bi_stat_cd, h.bi_stat_desc, h.bi_priority_cd, h.bi_priority_desc, h.svc_ord_typ, h.svc_ord_desc, h.pm_actvty_typ_cd, h.pm_actvty_typ_desc, h.ticket_stat_cd, h.svc_ord_stat_desc, h.priority_cd, h.priority_desc, h.cause_cd, h.cause_desc, h.co_cd, h.bus_area_cd, h.ctrl_area_cd, h.cstctr_cd, h.cstctr_desc, h.profit_cntr_cd, h.profit_cntr_desc, h.sls_area_cd, h.sls_area_desc, h.sls_office_cd, h.sls_office_desc, h.sls_grp_cd, h.sls_grp_desc, h.automated_call_flag, h.etl_job_invk, h.etl_job_name, h.etl_batch_id, h.etl_create_dtm, h.etl_lod_dtm, h.etl_msng_fk_flag'
'                                                              Index Cond: (h.svc_ord_misc_dim_id = a.svc_ord_misc_dim_id)'
'                                                              Buffers: shared hit=37253'
'                                      ->  Index Scan using svc_actvty_degen_dim_pk on public.dmt_mas_svc_actvty_degen_dim e  (cost=0.43..1.48 rows=1 width=166) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=36276)'
'                                            Output: e.svc_actvty_id, e.svc_actvty_ssk, e.src_sys_cd, e.actvty_typ_cd, e.svc_ord_nbr, e.ntfcn_nbr, e.svc_actvty_doc_nbr, e.svc_actvty_doc_ln_nbr, e.oper_nbr, e.row_nbr, e.ntfcn_id, e.work_cmplt_flag, e.final_cnfrm_flag, e.cause_lsk, e.bill_cd, e.uom_cd, e.cstctr_cd, e.bus_area_cd, e.gl_acct_cd, e.actvty_typ_lsk, e.svc_ord_ssk, e.ntfcn_ssk, e.equip_ssk, e.tchn_ssk, e.truck_sloc_ssk, e.brnch_ssk, e.prod_ssk, e.start_dtm, e.end_dtm, e.etl_job_invk, e.etl_job_name, e.etl_batch_id, e.etl_create_dtm, e.etl_lod_dtm, e.etl_msng_fk_flag'
'                                            Index Cond: (e.svc_actvty_id = b.svc_actvty_id)'
'                                            Filter: (e.start_dtm >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)'
'                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 0'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=145045'
'                                ->  Index Scan using equip_store_dim_pk on public.dmt_mas_equip_store_dim c  (cost=0.43..1.29 rows=1 width=732) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=33678)'
'                                      Output: c.equip_store_id, c.src_sys_cd, c.equip_store_ssk, c.equip_ssk, c.shipto_cust_ssk, c.shipto_cust_id, c.equip_store_cd, c.equip_nbr, c.equip_desc, c.shipto_cd, c.shipto_desc, c.equip_shipto_addr_1, c.equip_shipto_addr_2, c.equip_shipto_addr_3, c.equip_shipto_addr_4, c.equip_shipto_city, c.equip_shipto_state_cd, c.equip_shipto_pstl_cd, c.equip_shipto_cntry_cd, c.tech_nbr, c.brnch_id, c.svc_brnch_ssk, c.svc_brnch_cd, c.equip_typ_cd, c.equip_typ_desc, c.begin_wrnty_dte, c.end_wrnty_dte, c.first_svc_dtm, c.install_dtm, c.etl_job_invk, c.etl_job_name, c.etl_batch_id, c.etl_create_dtm, c.etl_lod_dtm, c.etl_msng_fk_flag, c.actv_stat_flag, c.del_flag, c.sls_ord_nbr, c.sls_ord_dtl_nbr'
'                                      Index Cond: (c.equip_store_id = b.equip_store_id)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=134827'
'                          ->  Index Scan using prod_dim_pk on public.dmt_mas_prod_dim d  (cost=0.42..1.23 rows=1 width=696) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=33678)'
'                                Output: d.prod_id, d.src_sys_cd, d.prod_cd, d.prim_prod_desc, d.brand_cd, d.brand_desc, d.prod_svc_typ_cd, d.prod_svc_typ_desc, d.base_uom_cd, d.base_uom_desc, d.resp_div_cd, d.resp_div_name, d.prod_stat_cd, d.prod_stat_desc, d.prod_hier_lvl_1_cd, d.prod_hier_lvl_1_desc, d.prod_hier_lvl_2_cd, d.prod_hier_lvl_2_desc, d.prod_hier_lvl_3_cd, d.prod_hier_lvl_3_desc, d.prod_hier_lvl_4_cd, d.prod_hier_lvl_4_desc, d.prod_hier_lvl_5_cd, d.prod_hier_lvl_5_desc, d.prod_hier_lvl_6_cd, d.prod_hier_lvl_6_desc, d.prod_hier_lvl_7_cd, d.prod_hier_lvl_7_desc, d.prod_hier_lvl_8_cd, d.prod_hier_lvl_8_desc, d.sap_matl_prc_grp_cd, d.sap_matl_prc_grp_desc, d.sat_prod_prc_grp_lvl_1_name, d.sat_prod_prc_grp_lvl_2_name, d.hrmz_prod_cd, d.hrmz_prod_desc, d.src_sys_del_flag, d.etl_job_name, d.etl_job_invk, d.etl_load_dtm, d.etl_create_dtm, d.etl_batch_id, d.etl_msng_fk_flag, d.prod_series_cd, d.prod_series_desc, d.prod_ctgy_cd, d.prod_ctgy_desc, d.cust_prod_ctgy_cd, d.cust_prod_ctgy_desc, d.door_typ_cd, d.door_typ_desc, d.alloc_mthd_cd, d.alloc_mthd_desc'
'                                Index Cond: (d.prod_id = b.prod_id)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=134714'
'                    ->  Index Scan using dmt_mas_svc_ord_degen_dim_svc_ord_id_key on public.dmt_mas_svc_ord_degen_dim o  (cost=0.43..1.26 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=33678)'
'                          Output: o.svc_ord_id, o.src_sys_cd, o.svc_ord_nbr, o.prim_ntfcn_nbr, o.svc_ord_ssk, o.prim_ntfcn_ssk, o.soldto_cust_ssk, o.shipto_cust_ssk, o.street_addr_1, o.street_addr_2, o.street_addr_3, o.street_addr_4, o.city, o.state, o.pstl_cd, o.cntry, o.ticket_dtm, o.rqst_start_dtm, o.rqst_end_dtm, o.basic_start_dtm, o.basic_end_dtm, o.sched_start_dtm, o.sched_end_dtm, o.act_start_dtm, o.act_end_dtm, o.mlfctn_start_dtm, o.mlfctn_end_dtm, o.close_dtm, o.debit_memo_dtm, o.po_nbr, o.nte_amt, o.rpt_by, o.vend_cd, o.timezone, o.timezone_offset, o.etl_job_invk, o.etl_job_name, o.etl_batch_id, o.etl_create_dtm, o.etl_lod_dtm, o.etl_msng_fk_flag'
'                          Index Cond: (o.svc_ord_id = b.svc_ord_id)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=134873'
'              ->  Hash  (cost=35.85..35.85 rows=1185 width=280) (actual time=0.738..0.738 rows=1185 loops=1)'
'                    Output: br.brnch_cd, br.brnch_name, br.brnch_id'
'                    Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 85kB'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=24'
'                    ->  Seq Scan on public.dmt_mas_brnch_dim br  (cost=0.00..35.85 rows=1185 width=280) (actual time=0.008..0.371 rows=1185 loops=1)'
'                          Output: br.brnch_cd, br.brnch_name, br.brnch_id'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=24'
'Planning time: 4.250 ms'
'Execution time: 6258.698 ms'
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name execution plan added.

Comment: try to increase join_collapse_limit to 16

Comment: @PavelStehule I'm not familiar with `join_collapse_limit`. can you elaborate on why increasing this limit would help?

Comment: you can try it only per session where you can check the effect of this change. This option increase a space for optimization - there is higher change to find better plan, but it can increase (sometimes significantly) planning time.

Comment: Do you have an index on `dmt_mas_svc_actvty_fact(svc_ord_id)`? But it seems you are select (nearly) all column from that table, so an index might not be helpful. Note that the Hash Join you mentioned only takes about 1.8 seconds. The 5,4 seconds shown in the plan is the time **including** all children of that node. The `distinct` obfuscated with a `group by` is often a sign that joining against a sub-select that reduces the number of rows *before* joining might help. But it's hard to tell from just the query itself.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes `svc_ord_id` is indexed